# click event Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

how can i create andfire bootstrap popover in same event?

```
 $('.btShowWkf').mouseover(function(e){
        debugger;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        //var el= e.target;
        $(this).popover({
            id: "customPop",
            title: "QUAD-HCM Popover",
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                return '<span style="color:red;font-size:1.3em;">WOKFLOW</span><br><span style="color:darkgrey;">YESSSSSS.</span>';
            },
            container: 'body',
            fontColor: "#000",
            borderColor: "#000",
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            onCreate: null,
            onVisible: null,
            childToAppend: null,
            keepData: false,
            disableHeader: false,
            trigger: "click",
            placement: "top"
        });
        $(this).trigger('click');
        myTableName.workflowLabels(null,$(this));


    });
```

I need to create and fire with the same click event because theres to many rows and for performance and memory and dont want to attach all the popover at once.
Thanks.

Comment: onmouseover you want to initialize the popover and trigger it to show. is it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btShowWkf').mouseover(function(e){    
     $(this).popover({
            id: "customPop",
            title: "QUAD-HCM Popover",
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                return '<span style="color:red;font-size:1.3em;">WOKFLOW</span><br><span style="color:darkgrey;">YESSSSSS.</span>';
            },
            container: 'body',
            fontColor: "#000",
            borderColor: "#000",
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            onCreate: null,
            onVisible: null,
            childToAppend: null,
            keepData: false,
            disableHeader: false,
            placement: "top"
    });
    $(this).popover("show");
});
```